# API Gateway timesout on invoking lambda function

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have an API that invokes a lambda function. Number of invocations are between 20-30 every hour. Out of these 1 or 2 are getting timeout exceptions and could not invoke lambda functions. Not sure if this is caused by unavailable lambda containers or something else. API gateway logs dosen't show any 504 errors. Any inputs suggesting on what might be going wrong are appreciated.

Comment: What is the timeout set to on the backing lambda?

Comment: Timeout on API call is 8 seconds and backend lambda is 7 sec.